# create a huge array in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I want to create an array 2D contain like this.

that every tuple contain three numbers that represent the coloring RGB system

```
[
(0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,0,2)  (0,0,3)  (0,0,4)  (0,0,5)  (0,0,6)  (0,0,7)

(0,0,8) (0,0,9) (0,0,10) (0,0,11) (0,0,12) (0,0,13) (0,0,14) (0,0,15)
 
(0,0,16) (0,0,17) (0,0,18)  (0,0,19)  (0,0,20)  (0,0,21)  (0,0,22)  (0,0,23) 
.....    
(250,250,242) (250,250,243) (250,250,244) .... (250,250,250)                                                    
]
```

and the same but for a common RGB, number .this array for example 8x8
and to give a key to each tuple that refers to the name of this color
for example ,like (0,0,0) => black

--
I tried .. and did like this

```
arr2 = np.array([(i,i,i) for i in range(250)] , dtype = [('Red','i2'),('Green','i2'),('Blue','i2')])
print(arr2)
```

but that did not work!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you tried to implement this already? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: and `(0,0,2)` is `'not_quite_that_black'`? so you have 16 million and change names for colors? what is this good for? your code only creates (0,0,0),(1,1,1),...,(249,249,249) because it only uses one running variable...

Comment: for the first array, no need for names. just I need the data, as an array 2D.
I know my code is wrong, but that what I have reached.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**:

```
>>> colors = [(r, g, b) for r in range(256) for g in range(256) for b in range(256)]
>>> colors[:10]     # First 10 colors
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4), (0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 6), (0, 0, 7), (0, 0, 8), (0, 0, 9)]
>>> colors[-10:]    # Last 10 colors
[(255, 255, 246), (255, 255, 247), (255, 255, 248), (255, 255, 249), (255, 255, 250), (255, 255, 251), (255, 255, 252), (255, 255, 253), (255, 255, 254), (255, 255, 255)]
>>> len(colors)     # Numbers of colors in RGB    
16777216
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a dictionary.

```
dict = {(0, 0, 0): "black", ... }
```

You could then search for color with the RGB like this.

```
print(dict[(0, 0, 0)])
```